# Why does Application_BeginRequest() fire twice when refreshing browser?

Tags: asp.net

I'm observing some really confusing behavior with the Application_BeginRequest event in my Global.asax file (in an ASP.NET MVC app).  When running through the debugger, if I Refresh my browser (IE7), this event fires twice.  If I click a link or otherwise manually request a page, it fires once - as expected.

Why does a refresh cause BeginRequest to fire twice?

I'm observing this with a brand new MVC project with the following addeded to Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() { 
    //executed twice
}
```

For context, I'm trying to add a new object to the HttpContext.Current.Items collection during this event, so it will persist through the entire request process. Obviously, I don't want this to happen twice for a single refreshed request!

Comment: Are you performing any sort of URL redirection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure it's really 2 request to the same URL? I would think that the second is probably some dynamic JS, CSS or image file. Try to find out either with Fiddler or by looking at HttpContext.Current.Request.Uri in the debugger

Comment: Bingo! I didn't realize that this will fire for other content files. It seems the strangness with a refresh vs other requests is due to IE requesting all content (the url, css, js, etc) on a refresh, whereas click on a link or re-entering the url it was caching everything but the actual url request...

Answer (score 2):

Something that surprised me a while back was that if you have an img tag in your html that doesn't have a proper image path, some browsers will make a request to the original page.  [Here is a related blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bdill/archive/2009/01/25/ie-image-bug-website-performance-hit.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is occuring but I find it's easier to create a BaseController class and have all my controllers inherit from it. Alter the constructor to add your item to the HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference in your HTML to something that also passes the ASP.NET pipeline, like a dynamically generated image or something like that?