# ASP.NET Cookies BUG - multiple cookies duplicated randomly?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

It seems that there is annoying bug in ASP.NET cookie handling during writing of response-stream to the wire. `Set-Cookie` headers are multiplied randomly.

My example setup is: *ASP.NET MVC4* on *IIS8 express* server, but same issue happens on *IIS7 integrated mode*, and I found posts about the same issue *IIS6* back in 2009. It seem to be issue exists for a while.

For example, in Global.asax.cs I subscribe to BeginRequest event and write to HttpResponse.Cookie collection in my event handler:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("OnBeginRequest", "0"));
    }
}
```

This will, already, output "OnBeginRequest" Set-Cookie header twice. But, if similar is done for all HttpApplication events (AuthenticateRequest, AcquireRequestState, etc... total ~20 events), header of http response sent to browser will have LOT of duplicates written. It's also obvious after which event writing of cookies start from begging.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnMapRequestHandler=7; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnMapRequestHandler=7; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostMapRequestHandler=8; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAcquireRequestState=9; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAcquireRequestState=10; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreRequestHandlerExecute=11; path=/
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnMapRequestHandler=7; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostMapRequestHandler=8; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAcquireRequestState=9; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAcquireRequestState=10; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreRequestHandlerExecute=11; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostRequestHandlerExecute=12; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnReleaseRequestState=13; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostReleaseRequestState=14; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnMapRequestHandler=7; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostMapRequestHandler=8; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAcquireRequestState=9; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAcquireRequestState=10; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreRequestHandlerExecute=11; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostRequestHandlerExecute=12; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnReleaseRequestState=13; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostReleaseRequestState=14; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnUpdateRequestCache=15; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostUpdateRequestCache=16; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnLogRequest=17; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostLogRequest=18; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnEndRequest=19; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthenticateRequest=1; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthenticateRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAuthorizeRequest=3; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAuthorizeRequest=4; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnResolveRequestCache=5; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostResolveRequestCache=6; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnMapRequestHandler=7; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostMapRequestHandler=8; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAcquireRequestState=9; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAcquireRequestState=10; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreRequestHandlerExecute=11; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostRequestHandlerExecute=12; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnReleaseRequestState=13; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostReleaseRequestState=14; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnUpdateRequestCache=15; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostUpdateRequestCache=16; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnLogRequest=17; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostLogRequest=18; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnEndRequest=19; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreSendRequestContent=20; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPreSendRequestHeaders=21; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 10:47:20 GMT
Content-Length: 4002
```

Even worse, if same cookie is written in 1 event handler, then updated in another, duplicates with different values will appear in the header.

Are there any settings or workaround that can prevent this behavior of default `HttpResponse.Cookies` collection?

Comment: Use something like `Debug.Write("Application_BeginRequest File : " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);` to see what is calling that.

Comment: Application_BeginRequest() is called only once per request. Issue happens at lower level, perhaps in System.Web.dll, not in the user-code.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139566/why-does-application-beginrequest-fire-twice-when-refreshing-browser

Comment: Yes, I've seen that one too. Double-checked before writing post. Events do not fire twice. Problem is created when you write to HttpResponse.Cookies at different stages of request life-cycle (begin-request, session-start, etc...). Additionally, in the post you refer to, cookie would be written in 2 different request headers (page and css file), instead of multiple times in the same header.

Answer (score 6):

The bug impacting IIS 7 is probably not the same bug as impacted IIS6. This bug was fixed as of 4.7, he bug in question has the following ID: `DevID 289778`.

### Background

Here is a description of it:
In IIS7, every time you leave the asp.net pipeline to return to the IIS pipeline, cookie headers are added, if needed. In integrated mode, you leave the asp.net pipeline between most events.

So when it writes out cookies as needed, it checks if any cookies have been removed. If not, it checks if any cookies have been added. If so it adds a header for that cookie. It also checks if any cookies have been modified. If so it adds a header for it. While it iterates the cookies, it makes note of any that are modified.

If any cookies were removed, or any were modified then it deletes all Set-Cookie headers, and writes out a new set. (Or at least it tries. If headers have been flushed, then obviously this is not possible.)

So far so good. However upon re-entering the managed pipeline, we read any response headers back in and reconstitute the response cookies. This is needed since some unmanaged module may have added new response cookies. When doing so it does not set the added flag for any cookies copied from response headers.  So so far everything is still good, right?

### The Bug

Well not exactly. Every time a cookie is added to (or removed from) the `Response.Cookies` collection, the `Request.Cookies` collection is completely reloaded, and then the response cookies are added to it, setting the add flag on the `HttpCookie` object again. This is the bug. This causes the Added flag to be set on every response cookie every time any other cookie is added or removed.

This means that if you don't modify or remove any cookies, but you add at least one, then all the cookies that were previously added in other pipeline stages will get duplicated. However, if you change any cookie, or remove any cookie from the `Response.Cookies` collection, then you eliminate all the duplicates that previously occurred.

### The Hackish Workaround

To work around this bug, simply add and remove some arbitrary cookie, or modify a cookie during the same event as the headers get written out. Normally this would be `EndRequest`, except if you use `Server.Transfer`, `Server.Redirect`, `Response.Flush`, or `Reponse.End` (unless you set the `endReponse` parameter to false) anywhere in the app, in which case you must do this in the same event that those occur. Also don't forget about any occurances of those that occur in libraries, or any HttpModules you use. Basically, you want to just add the following code to every single event:

```
try{
   var guid=Guid.NewGuid();
   context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(guid.ToString(),string.Empty);
   context.Response.Cookies.Remove(guid.ToString());
}
catch(HttpException)
{
   //This means the headers were already written,
   //in which case we need not do anything.
}
```

Comment: We were seeing this in .NET 4.6. Judging by https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blame/master/System.Web/HttpCookieCollection.cs#L102, this was fixed in .NET 4.7+

Comment: The description of DevID `251951` at https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blame/master/System.Web/HttpCookieCollection.cs#L85 does not seem to match the bug described by Nenad. I think the actual DevID of the issue is `289778`.

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee Yeah, looking into this, DevID 251951 does not fix the issue. Updated the post to reflect the real fix. It does potentially fix certain cases of the bug as a side, effect, but 4.7 added some additional code in two different places to fix this bug fully.

Comment: Other duplicated cookie bug description:  
Context: Web Forms application (using forms authentication and url rewrite)  
Issue: session cookie systematically sent twice (except for the first request received after application is compiled).  
Platform: IIS 10/.NET Framework 4.7.2  
  
Kevin solution does work on that bug (too).  
  
Notes:  
On an asp.net web form page, this workaround can be used on Load event.  
There is no need for a random cookie name.

Answer (score 1):

Other duplicated cookie bug description:
Context: Web Forms application (using forms authentication and url rewrite)
Issue: session cookie systematically sent twice (except for the first request received after application is compiled).
Platform: IIS 10/.NET Framework 4.7.2

Kevin solution does work on that bug (too).

Notes:
There is no need for a random cookie name.
On an asp.net web forms page, this workaround can be used on Load event.

Answer (score -1):

When you set any value to cookie, clear it first, with `.Clear()`

```
var cookie = this.Request.Cookies.Get("MyCookie");
if (cookie == null)
{
   cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
   this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
else
{
   cookie.Values.Clear();                       //crear firstly..
   cookie.Values.Add("AnyKey", "AnyValue");
}
```

Comment: Initially I thought it won't work, but actually does something. Repetitions are gone, but cookie values get corrupted in some cases, for example if some cookie is overwritten, others loose value (wtf?).

Set-Cookie: OnBeginRequest=; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnAquireRequest=2; path=/
Set-Cookie: OnPostAcquireRequestState=; path=/

But seems worth exploring.

Answer (score -1):

If you navigate between pages after changing cookie value without returning to client (server.Transfer) cookies will be duplicated.